# From a root node, reaching all the next vertices with a specific label

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I'm using igraph within R stat.

I have a network of vertices wich have two labels : "red" and "orange".

I created a "function", which, from a root node, finds the first next "red" vertices.

This function works, except that it uses global variables instead of returning a result. It's not very elegant. I want to improve my function so it returns a list of nodes but I don't know how to do it.

Here is the code :

```
library(igraph)

g <- make_tree(15, mode="undirected")
a <- as_adj_list(g)

V(g)$color <- "orange"
V(g)$color[c(3,5,8,9)] <- "red"

plot(g)
```

[image: tree graph]

From the first node, I want to return 3,5,8,9 but *not* 13

the function :

```
mydfs <- function(a, s, nodes=NULL) {
  nodes <- c(s, nodes)

  for (child in a[[s]]) {
    if (!(child %in% nodes)) {

      v <- V(g)[child]

      if(v$color=="red") {
        okNodes <<- c(okNodes, as.numeric(v))
        return
      } else {
        mydfs(a, child, nodes)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the result :

```
okNodes <- NULL # okNodes is a global variable which will stock the reached "red" vertices.
mydfs(a, 1) # mydfs([adjacency list], [root node])
okNodes 
# gives [1] 8 9 5 3. As you can see, the 13th node is not included as it follows the 3rd node which is red
```

You see that the 13th node is not included, which is what's specific of the function I want.

I'd like a function that doesn't use global variables. Also, the best I would have would be the corresponding list of paths.

```
okNodes <- mydfs(a, 1) 
okNodes
# gives [1] 8 9 5 3.
```

If any of you sees how to modify my function accordingly.

Comment: Your function errors out as there is no `dfs.f` function defined here - I think it needs to recursively call `mydfs()`?

Comment: yes, you're right. I had changed the function name in stackoverflow to make it more understandable and forgot to change it in the function. I've just edited my question accordingly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly, but it utilises `get.shortest.paths` to check all the paths from the specified node to a "red" node. It will return the complete path to each "red" node.

```
findRed <- function(graph,node) {
  paths  <- get.shortest.paths(graph,node,V(graph)[V(graph)$color=="red"])$vpath
  colors <- lapply(paths, function(x) V(graph)$color[x] )
  unique(Map(function(p,c) as.vector(p[seq(1,match("red",c))]), paths, colors))
}

findRed(g,14)
#[[1]]
#[1] 14  7  3
#
findRed(g,1)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 5
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 4 8
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 1 2 4 9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work ! It's a pretty nice solution indeed.But if any of you has an idea on how to modify my function, it would be nice. Just for information and learning !